# Two table join Postgres count child rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: posts and replies.

The post table contains these columns

```
postid | forumName | title | content
```

The replies table contains these columns

```
replyid | content | postid
```

I would like to have a sql query that joins these tow tables and returns for each Forum

```
forumName | Total Number of Posts | Total Number of Replies
```

This is hard as the two tables are linked using postId.

```
select forum, count(id) as postsNum
from posts
group by forum
order by postsNum desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
select p.forum
      ,count(distinct id) as posts
      ,count(r.replyid) as replies
from posts p
inner join replices r
    on p.postid = r.postid
group by p.forum
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It worked. I and new and don't have enough reputation to assign this as answer.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit:     

select posts.forum
      , count(distinct posts.id) as posts
      , count(replies.postid) as replies
from posts 
inner join replies 
    on posts.id = replies.postid
group by posts.forum